# Creating a horizontal Tumbler or circular SwipeView in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'd like to replace a `SwipeView` with an `Tumbler` in QML as I prefer the notion, that there is no first and no last `Item`.
The problem is, I can't find any other way to get this `Tumbler` tumble horizontally instead of vertically, but to rotate it by -90° and then rotate the `Item`s back by +90°

This is my code so far, and works as expected:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: root
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Row {
        id: buttons
        spacing: 2
        Button {
            text: '0'
            onClicked: tumbl.currentIndex = 0
        }
        Button {
            text: '1'
            onClicked: tumbl.currentIndex = 1
        }
        Button {
            text: '2'
            onClicked: tumbl.currentIndex = 2
        }
        Button {
            text: '3'
            onClicked: tumbl.currentIndex = 3
        }
    }

    Tumbler {
        id: tumbl
        rotation: -90 // <---- Rotate there
        anchors {
            top: buttons.bottom
            left: buttons.left
            right: buttons.right
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        model: 4
        delegate: Rectangle {
            rotation: 90 // <---- Rotate back
            color: 'red'
            border.width: 15
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }
        }
        visibleItemCount: 1
        Component.onCompleted: contentItem.interactive = false
    }
}
```

You can see the two lines, in which I do the rotation marked with a comment.
Does anybody know a way to either produce this circular behavior with a `SwipeView` or to change the tumble-orientation of the tumbler without this rotation trick?

Comment: You should consider yourself lucky such a minor hack got you what you wanted. I personally have found it much easier to implement my own controls with the particular required behavior than to try and modify the stock controls, which are IMHO half-baked and limited in their design. A circular swipe view would be fairly trivial to implement anyway.

Comment: Yeah, it might be, that it is better to implement it from scratch, but as the QtQuick.Controls tend to be only half-way documented (*e.g in the documentation, it is not mentioned that I do not have to import the `QtQuick.Extras`, and that this `Tumbler` has a default-column*) I thought, it might be, that there is a of-the-shelf-solution to this. I usually assume that the *trolls* do know better, how to implement the behavior in the most efficient way, than I would know, without much research... though I admit, to implement the circular swipe from scratch would not be that hard.

Comment: It is not a good thing to assume :) Being good at programming and being good at designing software are very different things. Programmers in big companies generally are not concerned with the design, they do as they are told. I think the programmers at Qt are indeed very good, but their architects tend to be somewhat to very lacking. And it doesn't matter how much of a good builder you are if the plans you are paid to follow are crooked.

Comment: @ddriver, we all know you hate the controls, OK. You are the first comment in almost every question about this stuff. Let it rest. It's just not contributing to the discussion in a constructive manner at all. As for the actual question: a horizontal Tumbler isn't supported yet; there is this bug report if you're interested: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47513

Comment: @Mitch thank you! The problems with the height have been something that I saw as well, when you try to show more then one Item at the same time. I will see when I'll find the time to implement it myself, and might provide an answer to this question at some point in time.

Comment: `Extras` were the previous enterprise controls which were merged with original quick controls as the two were part of seperate offerts (commercial vs. open source) up until qt 5.5. That said, controls 1 suck in a variety of ways. No big deal. FWIW my experience with controls 2 is happy, at the moment, and I would simply obliterate controls 1. Ok, enough chit-chat, @derM you can implement that with a `PathView`.