# Delete images from automatically scrolling Row in Flickable

Tags: qml, qt6

**Background.qml**

```
import QtQuick
Flickable{
    id:flickable
    anchors.fill:parent
    contentWidth:row.implicitWidth
    interactive:false
    Row{
        id:row
        anchors.fill:parent
    }
    Timer{
        interval:10;
        running:true;
        repeat:true
        onTriggered:{
            if(flickable.atXEnd){
                Qt.createComponent('Pic.qml').createObject(row)
            }
            flickable.contentX++
        }
    }
}
```

**Pic.qml**

```
import QtQuick
Image{
    sourceSize.height:parent.height
    fillMode:Image.PreserveAspectFit
    asynchronous:true
    source:'file://'+RandomImage
}
```

This continuously scrolls a strip of randomly chosen images from left to right.

This works nicely, but the only problem that remains is that images that scroll offscreen need to be deleted.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: ListView does this automatically if you can change the way your code works to use a model.

Comment: `createObject()` returns the object that was created. So you can theoretically maintain a list of those objects and then call their `destroy()` function when you want to delete them.

Comment: I would like to avoid using a ListView and a model in this case.
And yes, I obviously know how to delete the images, but not *when*. Basically what I'm looking for is a signal that gets triggered as soon as an image is scrolled offscreen.

Comment: It seems you would have to watch an object's `x` property to determine if it has gone outside its bounds. There is no automatic signal to tell you when an object is offscreen.

Answer (score 2):

In the following code, I made use of a `Tumbler` that has 5 delegates, but only 2-3 are visible at any one time. Because of that the system creates and destroys delegates so that only 2-3 delegates are active at any one time. You'll note the delegates are being destroyed, because the colors of the first 5 delegates are different from the next 5 delegates, i.e. when the `Tumbler` loops back to 0, the newly created delegates have a different random color.

To make the `Tumbler` work in horizontal mode, I borrowed code from [Creating a horizontal Tumbler or circular SwipeView in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868270/creating-a-horizontal-tumbler-or-circular-swipeview-in-qml)

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    Tumbler {
        id: tumbl
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        width: parent.height
        height: parent.height * 3
        rotation: -90 // <---- Rotate there
        model: 5
        delegate: Rectangle {
            rotation: 90 // <---- Rotate back
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
            border.width: 5
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }
        }
        visibleItemCount: 3
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: tumbl.currentIndex = (tumbl.currentIndex + 1 ) % 5
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACyHicjVLBbsIwDL33K3yZVLYRiiYOq7YTJw6TBuoPpK2VRmtjZFyGNPHvcwUUytCET3nPL07yXnyzJhZYyrL1xVfkB9DMKQhTvYk+rUP4iUAra5u8Rj6irnyZgnRsz9hQVMQbU2AQ5EVIYW1Z173g25dSnVhToXfVuXmAV114hJdewSRWPOnc8WsCkwm8jbVg1dEIUiFjr22oxDqFWU8oRKe6FFZYiA2uxovHDMffmJ5b9elSXVBNnKpnhl1u4w8rlWEbSmri0fM/aDSYkhOXyOZozGzQy3AnV1e8y+VTie5PwYcSd4PePvq72vqN13wXgs2c2qD7DrYfFJlvhtF3J2+t+jtNkuScTxuCD06/BbfnJBjXaOWKpJCxd04TO/0iU7TcPWPR3RfeIb7BPsEURvBw9Gkf7X8B8O3DxA==)

There is a quirk in the `Tumbler` code in that it doesn't allow for pixel-precise control of the horizontal scroll.

Below is an initial implementation of the same but with `ListView`. It also features 5 delegates and every time we go past the end it loops back to 0. Similar to the `Tumbler` scenario, old delegates (when they go offscreen) are deleted and new delegates are created:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listView
        anchors.fill: parent
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        model: 10
        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: ListView.view.height
            height: width
            color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
            border.width: 5
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: index
            }
        }
    }
    Timer {
        interval: 10
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: listView.contentX = (listView.contentX + 3) % (parent.height * 5)
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACjHicfVFNS8QwEL33V8xFaFWCInsJePKioOBKEa/ZdjYdTJNldrq7KPvfTWmtzS44h5D35iMvb6jdBBZYyrKj6jOjBKqH4IWD22avxiJ8ZxDjmbbyTrgfYR9Ua3AjPZHGV03grVqTcxo2htHLlAxMERqh4PU0UT1G+is+adxU2IYaY/vtzcREjNYIanjDSoy3DmdS+thTLc1s7K4/GiTbSFI3UHqoTzJVcIF1tEGxXZn8xUij2Pg6tHlx/Q8qkimrwDWyGuUsklyJBzmRPTetiu4gP/kz435DYr8G8jUektwxS2/DWVKLPF9YP31nUmO585681SDc4R+LGzRyQgZfMlmLjLPNqyquLmr9gHvIz8kruCvgAvLhQ+M+4BIWxSj0+AMrB7aS)

Unfortunately, there is an issue with the above implementation when it jumps from the 5th delegate back to the 0th delegate, the transition is not good.

To make it seamless, we can transition the solution to one involving two ListViews. As one is approaching the end of one ListView you transition to the other that's in the middle, and that gives time to prepare the other ListView to cycle back to the start without you seeing that transition jump:

```
ListView 1: -----ABCDE-----
ListView 2: ----------FGHIJ
ListView 1: -----BCDE-----A
ListView 2: ---------FGHIJ-
ListView 1: -----CDE-----AB
ListView 2: --------FGHIJ--
ListView 1: -----DE-----ABC
ListView 2: -------FGHIJ---
ListView 1: -----E-----ABCD
ListView 2: ------FGHIJ----
ListView 1: ----------ABCDE
ListView 2: -----FGHIJ----
ListView 1: ---------ABCDE-
ListView 2: -----GHIJ-----F
ListView 1: --------ABCDE--
ListView 2: -----HIJ-----FG
ListView 1: -------ABCDE---
ListView 2: -----IJ-----FGH
ListView 1: ------ABCDE---
ListView 2: -----J-----FGHI
ListView 1: -----ABCDE---
ListView 2: ----------FGHIJ
```

Here's an implementation of the dual ListView method depicted above:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listView2
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 15
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        interactive: false
        contentX: flickable.contentX
        delegate: Pic {
            visible: index >= 5 && index < 10
        }
    }
    ListView {
        id: listView1
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: 10
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        interactive: false
        contentX: (flickable.contentX + parent.width) % (parent.height * 10) -parent.width
        delegate: Pic {
            visible: index >= 0 && index < 5
        }
    }
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: parent.height * 15
        contentHeight: parent.height
        onContentXChanged: {
            if (contentX >= parent.height * 10) {
                Qt.callLater( () => { contentX -= parent.height * 10; } );
            }
        }
    }
    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 10
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: flickable.contentX += 1
    }
}

// Pic.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Rectangle {
    border.width: 5
    height: ListView.view.height
    width: height
    visible: index >= 0 && index < 5
    color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random())
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: index
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I've done something similar to the dual list approach when I needed a continuously scrolling text obect (like a marquee). I made two instances of the text and swapped between them depending on where I had scrolled to. It's a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
import QtQuick
Flickable{
    property int next:0
    id:flickable
    anchors.fill:parent
    contentWidth:row.implicitWidth
    interactive:false
    Row{
        id:row
        anchors.fill:parent
    }
    Timer{
        interval:1
        running:true
        repeat:true
        onTriggered:{
            if(flickable.atXEnd){
                Qt.createComponent('Pic.qml').createObject(row)
            }
            if(next===0){
                next=row.children[0].paintedWidth
            }
            if(flickable.contentX===next){
                row.children[0].destroy()
                next=0
                flickable.contentX=0
            }
            flickable.contentX++
        }
    }
}
```

So what I have done is declare an integer variable 'next', and set it to the paintedWidth of the first image in the row.

When the flickable's contentX matches this value, this image is deleted,  contentX is set to 0, and 'next' is updated to the paintedWidth of the next image, which now became the first.

So, quite simple solution.

I disabled asynchronous image loading though, because it causes some issues and doesn't provide any real benefits in this case.